# Center Grid according to Grid Cell in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a  Grid in my WPF application which is currently centered horizontally and vertically, no big deal. However, I would like to center my entire Grid according to a single Grid cell instead of the entire Grid. Is this possible? Here is a small illustration of what I want to achieve. I want the red cross to be the center.
[image]
The first picture shows the entire grid (The Grid is the green square) being centered, the second picture shows the entire grid being centered according to the cell with the red cross. Is this possible in XAML? I didn't provide any code on purpose because I don't really think that's necessary for this question, it's not like I have an error or something that doesn't work, I just have no clue how I would achieve this.

Comment: So you want the Red cross to be at the center of the screen, right? not the entire Grid that contains that cell, just the cell itself.

Comment: @LupuSilviu I did an update, hope it makes more sense now?

Comment: Maybe if you explain what problem you are trying to solve rather than how to implement this specific solution people will be able to provide better answers (and a better overall solution). So what is the purpose of this layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are outer Grid, inner Grid and element which should be centered. Outer and inner Grid have equal Row and Column weights. Layout adapts to resize

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
          Background="LightGray"
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Background="Green"/>

        <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Background="Cyan"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think you can achieve this, is only if your UI components have fixed size. This here is a code sample of how I achieved what you asked.

```
<Window x:Class="StackStuff.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackStuff"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<DockPanel>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Red"
          Width="150" Height="100" ClipToBounds="False">

        <Border Margin="0,-150,-30,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="50" 
                Width="180">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>
                <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black"/>

            </Grid>
        </Border>

        <Border Margin="0,0,-180,0" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" 
                Width="30" Height="100">

        </Border>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

As you can see, it has fixed size for all the cells.